# Adding Images/Attachments to Survey123 in Inbox

Tags: table, attachments, arcgis-survey123

**Project Background:** I have a spreadsheet of existing assets that I will be inspecting in an upcoming site visit. I uploaded the [Existing Assets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11FMGt6rnuJFmVpjBR9WXTkP_dFF0IAVZ) CSV file to AGOL to create a feature layer. A PDF of the feature layer screen is here ([Lake Pleasant Feature Layer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DDgkahzG3f9tWn4MtEqcyY-JX8YzBkN)) and the JSON is here ([Lake Pleasant JSON](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12dT73unAJrqeWxY2WmeJDRSnPUrLjOg8)). I then created a new survey in Survey123 Connect using the Feature Service radio button, and successfully created a survey in which I'm able to use the Inbox to view existing assets and modify any field I'd like.

**Question:** I want to be able to take photos of these existing assets during the site visit. I've read online that this is a shortcoming of Survey123 if modifying existing records, and that a repeat field needs to be added to create a related table. I attempted to create a repeat field for the images to be taken in the field; however, I get the error message "*The custom feature service submission_url is not compatible with this survey (Table PHOTOS not found)*" (also in the screenshot below).

How can I fix this problem?

---

[XLSForm](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MFaeC1luUABz3LCCXxaXkrIdDxWAwYE4)

[Existing Assets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11FMGt6rnuJFmVpjBR9WXTkP_dFF0IAVZ)

[Lake Pleasant Feature Layer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DDgkahzG3f9tWn4MtEqcyY-JX8YzBkN)

[Lake Pleasant JSON](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12dT73unAJrqeWxY2WmeJDRSnPUrLjOg8)

[image: Error Screenshot]

Comment: @SonofaBeach The repeat field is needed if you are updating an existing record. If you add the image at the time of record creation, it does not need to be in a repeat field.

Comment: Correct.  I've deleted my comment.